# Div toggle on checkbox but detect click when outside of the div to toggle off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to make my burger menu detect click when outside of the menu (.NavMenu) and change the hamburger checkbox back to unselected.

I've tried using `event.stopPropagation();` and trying to detect clicks in the document but my javascript knowledge is really limited so I am either not being able to show .NavMenu at all or .NavMenu closes when clicked outside but the hamburger menu stays as if it was open (X).

Can anyone help me with how to get the menu to close when clicked outside of the div that will also trigger the checkbox?

http://jsfiddle.net/s9ndequ2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add id 'burgerMenu' on div with class='NavMenu'.

And modify your JavaScript as

```
$('#burger').click(function() {
     if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".NavMenu").show();       
     } else {
        $(".NavMenu").hide();
     }
    });  
    $('body').click(function(event){
      removeBurger(event)
    })
    //this detects that user has clicked outside the menu
    function removeBurger(e){
      var targ;
      if (!e) {
          var e = window.event;
      }
      if (e.target) {
          targ=e.target;
      } else if (e.srcElement) {
          targ=e.srcElement;
      }
      if(targ.id!="burgerMenu" && targ.id!="burger"){
        if ( $('#burger').is(':checked')) {
        $(".NavMenu").hide();
        $( "#burger" ).prop( "checked", false );
      }
    }
    }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks! The X when the hamburger menu is open for me doesn't close it when clicked?

Comment: This I believe isn't being detected `else {
        $(".NavMenu").hide();
     }`

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/s9ndequ2/43/. Just added 2 more conditions in the body click event . It is working now.

Comment: thanks for your help some really useful bits I've learnt from both versions and now all working!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by giving some id or class to the main div which will holding your page contents and then in script you can detect whether click has been performed inside that div or not :

Considering your main div has class **mainDiv** you can add below snippet to your script to achieve what you have asked for :

```
$(".mainDiv").click(function(){
    if($('#burger').is(':checked'))
    $('#burger').click();
});
```

Comment: This is interesting, is it possible to $(**!**".NavMenu").click(function() where if the click is not in NavMenu then it closes?

Comment: I think above code is also doing the same thing @Beth, we can only detect where user has clicks I am not aware of any way of detecting where user has not clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this at your fiddle:

```
$('#burger').click(function(event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
 if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(".NavMenu").show();       
 } else {
    $(".NavMenu").hide();
 }
});  

$('body').click(function() {
  if ( $('#burger').is(':checked')) {
    $(".NavMenu").hide();
    $( "#burger" ).prop( "checked", false );
  }
})

$('.NavMenu').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s9ndequ2/2/

Comment: Thanks alot but I need the div to stay open if the click is inside it, but if the click is on the hamburger or the red, etc to close

Comment: That's almost exactly it, but the X hamburger for me doesn't close it?

Comment: This `else {
    $(".NavMenu").hide();
 }` doesn't seem to get triggered on the second click to close (X) on the hamburger